# X-ray characteristic radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, x-rays

A high speed electron knocks an orbital electron in the atom. This collision creates a vacancy that is filled by an electron from a higher energy level. My question is, what happen with both electrons after the collision? (high speed electron and the knocked electron)

Comment: Off we go, into the wild blue yonder... Eventually they land jobs filling orbitals around other atoms.

Comment: Or somethimes they have to moonlight ... taking part-time jobs in several atoms that form a vertical trust^W^W benzene ring.

Comment: @JonCuster at should be an Answer.

Comment: They also emit photons during these changes.

Answer (score 2):

Its a  many particle interactive  system and electrons are being knocked out from many such atoms  from various shells-

they can be caught by some other atoms if a suitable place is available in their arrangements or

get out loosing their energies by collision /radiation  and  transforming to mainly thermal energies.

The efficiency is at a level  that only 1%   of the total energy input  gets back as X-rays.

The Tube target  is to be cooled continuously  by water  otherwise the target can melt so a lot of energy of electrons convert to heat and electromagnetic radiation.